# Is there a way to use loaded Service Account to access google sheets in Cloud Run?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, service-accounts

I am currently looking for a way to read data from a Sheet in Python from a GCP Cloud Run instance. A service account (to which I shared the sheet) is loaded during the deployment of the instance and I was wondering if it was possible to use this service account directly without loading its key, as the instance is already using the account.

If you have any idea on how to do it I'll be happy.
Thanks

Comment: Do not use a service account to bypass user credentials for services such as drive, calendar, sheets, etc. `Warning: Service accounts should only be used for performing delegation where the effective identity is that of an individual user in a domain. Using the service account as a common owner to create many shared documents can have severe performance implications. Additionally, service accounts may not acquire additional storage quota, nor do they act as members of a domain.` https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-auth#perform_domain-wide_delegation_of_authority

Comment: It's a sheet that is used as a kind of shared db and the service account is only here to read data from the sheet. For me it's the best way here for my particular needs.
Thanks for the advice though, I didn't know about the performance issues

Comment: You will quickly find your app blocked with this error message: `Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A service account is an email, as any user account. If you need to access a user Google Sheet document to perform some processing on the data, you can simply share the sheet with the service account email. Put it in "Viewer" for read only or in "Editor" if you also want to update the sheet.

Then in your code, you need to create a credential, with the Cloud Run service account (not a key that you have on your side). The important part here, is to correctly scope the credential.

And then you can use the Sheet API to interact when the document.

```
    from googleapiclient.discovery import build
    import google.auth

    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform']

    default_credentials, project_id = google.auth.default(scopes=SCOPES)
    # The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
    SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'YOUR DOCUMENT ID'
    SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'A1:C1'

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=default_credentials)

    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    to_ret = "Result \n"

    if not values:
        to_ret += "\n" + 'No data found.'
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        to_ret += "\n" + 'Results:'
        print('Results:')
        for row in values:
            to_ret += "\n" + row[0]
            print(row)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the google.auth.default() was the part I didn't find!!